# Inheritance C++ (Diamond dread)

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have the following problem with inheritance (I would love to google it, but don't know the correct keywords it seems).

I have a `Module` class that implements `IModule` interface with function `A()`. I also have `ClientModule` class that inherits `Module` class and implements `IClientModule` interface with function `B()` that inherits `IModule` interface. This is where I am starting to get ambiguity and **double inheritance problems**.

Here is the class diagram that should tell a bit more about the problem:

[image]

I need to have separated access to `Module` class with `IModule` interface and `ClientModule` with `IClientModule` interface that offers access to `IModule` interface as well.

Comment: It would be much more clear if your question used the same class names as your diagram..

Comment: Why isn't the `IBase` interface in the figure?

Comment: Sounds like Java or C#

Comment: Sorry, will correct the mistakes :S

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647114/implementing-multiple-interfaces-in-c

Comment: Looks like the diamond inheritance problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379053/diamond-inheritance-c

Comment: @Marc This is not a diamond inheritance problem as far as I know.

Comment: @krizajB `ClientModule` inherits from `IModule` through both `IClientModule` and `Module` == diamond inheritance. Or am I missing something?

Comment: why doesn't virtual inheritance work in this case?

Comment: I was thinking of adding access to IModule interface to IClientModule with getter function, but there must be a better way to solve this kind of problems.

Comment: @10WaRRioR01 Who virtual inherits whom?

Comment: @krizajB i dont' get why can't you virtual inherit everything from IModule

Comment: @MarcClaesen Yeah, it seems so .. thank you for clearing that for me.
WaRRioR0: Testing :)

Comment: @krizajB - This is diamond inheritance to a T. Make `Module` and `IClientModule` inherit virtually from `IModule`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make IClientModule not inherit IModule (and probably rename it IClient). In ClientModule, just inherit from Module and implement IClient.

Or, an alternative solution written after reading your comments:

Make your ClientModule class inherit from IClientModule as in your example. However, instead of inheriting from Module, simply give ClientModule a member variable that is a Module, and forward the calls to this member where needed. Something like this:

```
class IModule { virtual void A() {} };
class Module : public IModule { ... };
class IClientModule : public IModule { virtual void B() {} };

class ClientModule : public IClientModule 
{
    // ...
    virtual void A() { _module.A(); }

private:
    Module _module;
};
```

However, it is likely still better to avoid mashing these together and use my original solution.

Comment: But I want IClientModule to inherit IModule, so i get full access with it (IModule and IClientModule)

Comment: What does 'get full access with it' mean? If your class inherits from IModule and from IClient, you can call methods of both interfaces on your ClientModule instance.

Comment: I won't have access to IModule functions and IClientModule functions in the same interface which I need.

Comment: I updated my answer with an alternative solution that would solve this problem.

Comment: @krizajB - In general it's a bad idea to design for derived class behaviors in a parent class. If the class `IClientModule` does not depend on any `IModule` functionality, making `IClientModule` derive from `IModule` is backhanded programming. Not a good idea. While virtual inheritance might solve your particular problem, following Wilbert's advice is oftentimes an even better advice.

Comment: This is what I had in mind .. but seemed to easy:
"was thinking of adding access to IModule interface to IClientModule with getter function, but there must be a better way to solve this kind of problems"

Comment: Don't give access to IModule using a getter. Forward the calls transparently. Don't expose implementation details.

Comment: Ye, your suggestion is way better, I understand it now .. ClientModule is Wrapper class of Module.
Basiclly I learned a lot, had no clue virtual inheritance or solution to diamond problem is an issues. Will research a bit more later on :)

Answer (score 3):

You are running into the "diamond inheritance" problem. Diamond inheritance has been discussed many times at this site and elsewhere. Make the inheritance of `class Module` and `class IClientModule` from `class IModule` virtual. This is not a perfect solution; sometimes the magic works, sometimes it doesn't. Where it doesn't work it's usually a case of demanding too much from inheritance.

Comment: In general, diamond inheritance should be avoided. Sometimes it cannot, but here he specifies everything from the start, so the solution should probably be to decompose the problem differently...

Comment: Does his situation really configure the diamond "problem"? I mean, `IModule` has no state, so the possibility of having two instances of it would not cause any collateral effects. I was about to suggest the same thing before noticing that.

Comment: Yes, this is the diamond problem because `IModule` has a method `A`. If `IModule::A()` is defined (rather than pure virtual), there's a problem with calling `A()` in `ClientModule`. Which `A` should be called, `IModule::A()` or `Module::A()`? There's also a problem if `IModule::A()` is pure virtual. Now `ClientModule` needs to define a method `A` because it's required but not defined on the `IModule` / `IClientModule` side of the diamond.

Comment: Complies .. will execute in few minutes.